# Find common lines between two files and also their line number

Tags: bash, shell

I want to find common lines between two files(large ones), one with 90 million lines and 1 with 100 thousands and also their line number.

```
comm -12 file1 file2
```

gives me the common lines, but I want to know the line number from the individual files as well

Comment: Do you mean the one with 100 thousand lines already has line numbers in it?

Comment: So what output do you expect if a line occurs at line 300 in file 1 and at line 500 in file 2? And what if it also occurs again at line 600 in file 2?

Comment: @MarkSetchell 300 commonline 500

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for me on my small test files - I'm not sure how it will perform on a file with 90 million lines.

```
tab=` printf '\t' `
join -t"$tab" -j2 <( cat -n file1 ) <( cat -n file2 )
```

This works because `cat -n` prepends a space-padded number followed by a tab character to each line.  The `join` then finds the common lines looking only at the stuff after the first tab.

After the join is complete, you should see the common lines, each followed by two numbers.  The first number is the line number from file1 and the second from file2.

Caveat: This will work if the files don't have tab characters already.  If that's not the case, you can use sed to convert the first tab to a 'safe' character.

```
safe="|"
join -t"$safe" -j2 \
  <( cat -n file1 | sed -e "s:\t:$safe:" ) \
  <( cat -n file2 | sed -e "s:\t:$safe:" )
```

Also, depending on how `join` is implemented, you may want to have the smaller file listed in the first process substitution and the larger one in the second.  This way the smaller file may all fit in memory and the larger file might be scanned and matching lines selected efficiently.  I have no idea if this is the case, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: +1 It's a good thing and may be fun to add more ideas on a question however I hope you'd also consider the time the question was posted, and also if the OP still cares about his question so perhaps you may not waste your energy on it. Cheers.

Comment: I have referred back to the XKCD so many times.. you have my bow, my axe and my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
awk '
FNR==NR {
    a[$0]++
    next
}
$0 in a {
    print
    delete a[$0]
}' file1 file2
```

If you also want to get the line numbers, you can use arrays of arrays in gawk version 4 like:

```
FNR==NR {
    a[$0][FNR]++
    file1=FILENAME
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    file2=FILENAME
}

$0 in a {
    b[$0][FNR]++
}

END {
    for(i in b) {
        print "Line: " i
        print " Line numbers in "file1":"
        printf "  "
        for (j in a[i])
            printf "%s,", j
        print ""
        print " Line numbers in "file2":"
        printf "  "
        for (j in b[i])
            printf "%s,", j
        print ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get halfway there with `diff`. This shows you the line numbers in `file1`, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any option to show the line number from `file2` - it seems `man diff` assumes that an unchanged line is also on the *same* line in both files, which is contrary to how it normally works.

```
diff --unchanged-line-format=$'%dn\t%L' --old-line-format='' --new-line-format='' file1 file2
```

Another half measure using [unified diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format):

```
diff -u file1 file2
```

This shows *different* lines with a bit of context, meaning you can *infer* which lines the common text is on. The lines starting with `@@` give you the line information. For example:

```
@@ -1,5 +2,10 @@
```

This means the next line starting with `-` or a space in the diff is line 1 in `file1`, and that the next line starting with `+` or a space is line 2 in `file2`. For your purposes you can ignore the numbers after the comma.